# Graphviz - how do I make the text in node in a digraph indented according to the text written in the file?

Tags: python, graphviz

[image]

I want to have that kind of indentation in the text of my node but I get

[image]

```
lines = ''
str = ''
with open('record.txt') as f:
    lines = f.read()
g = Digraph('G', filename = 'result_indent', node_attr = {'shape' : 'box'})
g.edge(lines, "node", label = "edge")
g.render(filename= 'new/result_indent')
```